# I can not get data from arduino to raspberry by USB

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, usb

I am having problems with getting data from the Arduino raspberries on USB port. When connecting to Windows in the port monitor, I see data that arrives from the GPS and accelerometer. But when connected to the raspberry data does not come. What could be the problem?

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200)


while 1:
    new_ser = ser.readline()
    print new_ser
```

dmesg | grep tty

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=656 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=416 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200 root=PARTUUID=b10cf8df-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
[    0.000282] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.665506] 3f201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 87, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    0.667000] console [ttyS0] disabled
[    0.667028] 3f215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 166, base_baud = 31250000) is a 16550
[    0.667075] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    3.509261] usb 1-1.4: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Comment: How have you connected arduino and raspberry pi?

Comment: @PareshLomate I using USB-cable. After 30-40 minutes the data began to be displayed. In connection with what it can be connected?

Comment: Also can you post your relevant arduino code?

Comment: @PareshLomate https://pastebin.com/NWYqMf7s

Comment: Don't you think while (gpsSerial.available()) in bool readgps() is blocking Serial communication? Please check it with print statement inside while loop. Check whether its taking long time.

Comment: There is another possibility that Serial interface is not keeping up with RPi. Try to add sleep time.sleep(0.01) of 10ms after print new_ser and varify.